# AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri. - issue with embeeded yammer on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, yammer

We have SharePoint online site where we have embedded yammer with script editor webpart. Suddently we are observing below error in Internet explorer

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri.

With this error application is getting crashed. For Chrome and Edge browser application is working as expected. Issue is with internet explorer only. Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue and contacted the Microsoft Premier support. Did not hear back as of now.  But to give more information on this issue below mention redirect uri is passing which is undefined

&redirect_uri=undefined%2Faad_refresh%
Which cause this issue.